# Chrome and Firefox view is not precise for small height

Tags: css, rendering, pixel-perfect

I'm trying to make a custom rounded underline with like so:

```
.underline:after{
   content: '';
   background: red;
   border-radius: 9999px;
   height: 3px;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   bottom: -3px;
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: inherit;
}
body{
font-size: clamp(1.4rem, -0.5rem + 3.2vw, 2rem);
  padding:1em;
}

ul{
  font-size: 3rem;
  list-style:none;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: red);
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 18px;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
  color:red;
  text-align: center;
}
li{
  position: relative;
}
.underline{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.underline::after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right:0px;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: currentColor;
  border-radius: 999px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a class="underline">hello</a></li>
    <li><a class="underline">hello</a></li>
    <li><a class="underline">hello</a></li>
    <li><a class="underline">hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem I'm facing is that the underlines height is not uniform, I don't care about the precise size  of the underline (if it's `2px` or `3px`) as long as them all to have the same height, while them all have `3px` height in the sheets and when inspecting, some underlines seem shorter than the others, and measuring actually approves it.

the rendered image on chrome (it happens also in Firefox, didn't text other browsers):

[image]

the inspector values:

[image]
[image]

Screen ruler measurement result (after scaling):

[image]

The odd part is that it seems like it depends on the `font-size` or the `a` height , if I make the screen size `1280px`+ the underlines have same height, when I make it smaller it become "randomized", some have the same height and some not, and it change again when I decrease the screen width (the font size depends in the screen size, `clamp(1.4rem, -0.5rem + 3.2vw, 2rem)`).

*(it's very hard to reproduce the same conditions to see the problem)*

Is this a bug? Is there a CSS rule to specify precision when rendering small elements?, is there a workaround?

Comment: May be a stupid clue but maybe try to swwitch `display:bock` to `flex` ? (really not sure about this as I can't reproduce your error)

Comment: Other possibility, set `min-height` property to the same value as your `height`

Comment: I think it's the subpixel values of the line being manipulated by the rendering engine since you're using an odd value and zooming in, did you try using an even value?

Comment: One reason why that could be going on is because the CSS unit 'px' is not defined as being one pixel on your monitor but rather being 1/96th of an inch. Because of your monitor resolution there could be an edge case where due to rounding float numbers it once renders 2 visual pixels and then 3 visual pixels. More information about pixels you can find here: https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/understanding-css-units/

Comment: try `border-bottom` and `padding-bottom` for ul li.  instead of `.underline::after`

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug it happens to me all the time, you should try to user their Incognito mode so that you would be able to see if your code is working as it defines.

Comment: It would have better been a comment

Comment: Sorry, I can't comment bc it requires 50 reputation thanks